# Directory Permissions Issue in one domain when site accessible from multiple domain

Tags: file-permissions

I have a Joomla 3.3 site that is accessible from sub.domain.com and domain.com (both pointing to the same Document Root). Both of them loads the site fine and the FTP account works as well but when I view the System Information->Directory Information when I am logged into the backend for domain.com, all the directories are unwriteable.

And yet when I log into the sub.domain.com backend and view the same information, the directories are all writeable. That means I can't install any components/upload images form the www.domain.com backend. Joomla was originally setup (using installation Wizard) under the sub.domain.com with the same FTP that is currently used. The people who manage the server are saying it is something to do with Joomla since the owner/permissions has not changed when I changed the Document Root of the live to use the current folder (shared by both domains).

So I am thinking what did I do wrong and where do I start looking? Thank you.

Comment: After a lot of hair pulling, finally figured out what the issue was. Just in case it helps someone else:

sub.domain.com was running PHP as FastCGI
domain.com was running PHP as Apache

Run the domain.com as FastCGI and voila, it is resolved!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have logged in as only one user when you uploaded the site. Two different logins means two different permissions. This is a precaution to safeguard two different users files from being overwritten. It has nothing to do with joomla, it's your shared server.

Log in to your control panel, use the file manager to zip up joomla and download it to your local machine and delete it from the server.

Unzip it and log in as the 2nd level domain user and ftp it back up. This was only one user owns both sets of files.

or just chown everything to one user.